# Reusing mocha test code

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I'm developing a NodeJS application and use Mocha for unit testing.

Let's say i have two very similar test suits. 
In fact those are tests for two classes which
implement the same interface.

For example:

suit_a.js

```
var A = require('./a');
describe(function () {
    var instance;
    beforeEach(function () {
        instance = new A();
    });
    it(function () {
        assert(instance.getSomeValue() === 1);
    });
});
```

suit_b.js

```
var B = require('./b');
describe(function () {
    var instance;
    beforeEach(function () {
        instance = new B({option: "option-value"});
    });
    it(function () {
        assert(instance.getSomeValue() === 1);
    });
});
```

Is there a way to remove code repetition? Is there a way to have two
different test suits, using same assertion code, but with different configuration
or something like that?

The only idea I have right now is to use some kind of source code generation,
but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the inner function to an extra file and `require` it.
In your case you need `new A()` and `new B(...)` extra, so either make them available outside or include them as a parameter to the require-result:

```
var t = require('innerTestGen');

var t1 = t.create(new A())
describe(t1);
var t2 = t.create(new B(...))
describe(t2);
```

Hope that helps?

Comment: This solves the problem quite well for now, the only minus is longer and less obvious stack-trace messages, thanks.